# turning lists into dictionary for frequencies (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been given two lists (wofo and role). One is just words, and the other one tells you if the word has been used as a metaphor in a text or not.
The first few entries look like this, if you print them:

**wofo:
Lichtfiguren
nachhängt
diese
Sterne
fallen**

**role:
Metapher
Anker
Anker
Metapher
Metapher**

(so the words don't have quotation marks - are they still strings?)

I am supposed to create two dictionaries. The first one should give the number of times a word has been used as a "Metapher", the other one how often a word has been used as an "Anker".

My first attempt was this
(I basically tried to put both list into one dictionary and then call the elements):

```
lemma_met = {}
lemma_ank = {}

wofo2 = wofo.split("\n")
role2 = role.split("\n")

dicitionary = dict(zip(wofo2, role2))

for elment in wofo:
    if dicitionary.get(element) == "Metapher":
        if element in lemma_met:
            lemma_met[element] += 1
        else:
            lemma_met[element] = 1
    elif dicitionary.get(element) == "Anker":
        if element in lemma_ank:
            lemma_ank[element] += 1
        else:
            lemma_ank[element] = 1
```

I have also tried this but both only give me empty dicitionary entries:

```
lemma_met = {}
lemma_ank = {}

for key in wofo:
    for value in role:
        if value == "Metapher":
            if key in lemma_met:
                lemma_met[key] += 1
            else:
                lemma_met[key] = 1
        elif value == "Anker":
            if key in lemma_ank:
                lemma_ank[key] += 1
            else:
                lemma_ank[key] = 1
```

Does anyone have an explanation for what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? Sorry, I am very new to python and writing code in general.
Is there an easier way of doing it?
Or is there a specific term I can google to find the answer?

Sorry, this question has probably been answered somewhere, but I cannot find it. I have been working on this problem for quite a while now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: how are you given wofo and role? because it looks like that may be the reason as you are not properly splitting the text to make them into lists

Comment: wofo and role are from a text document. Essentially there are two lines from a big document. We got them like this: 

columns = line.split()
        
        wofo = columns[2]
        role = columns[26]

Comment: `dicitionary = dict(zip(wofo2, role2))` won't work as you need if `wofo2` contains words repeated multiple times. You will lose information.

Comment: when you print are you printing wofo2 and role2 after doing split('/n')? because it might be that you need to do .split(' ' ) instead to get a list

Comment: Oh, this is good to know! Especially because I am specifically looking for words being used on multiple occasions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might likely work better for you:

```
lemma_met = {}
lemma_ank = {}

wofo2 = wofo.split("\n") # these may not be separating your strings into list
role2 = role.split("\n")
#wofo2 = wofo.split(" ") # these might likely be splitting your string into a list form which will work with your output.
#wofo2 = wofo.split(" ")

for wofo_elm, role_elm in zip(wofo2, role2): # allows you to go through both lists at the same time
    if role_elm == "Metapher": # instead look at the current role element
        if wofo_elm in lemma_met:
            lemma_met[wofo_elm] += 1 # check if the word is used in the dictionary
        else:
            lemma_met[wofo_elm] = 1
    elif role_elm == "Anker":
        if wofo_elm in lemma_ank:
            lemma_ank[wofo_elm] += 1
        else:
            lemma_ank[wofo_elm] = 1
```

Comment: Good answer. You could make `lemma_met` and `lemma_ank` defaultdicts to make the code more compact.

Comment: It did to an extent, but it still does not work perfectly. When I tried printing out lemma_met, this is what I was given (just the first few entries): 
{}
{'nachhängt': 1}
{'diese': 1}
{}
{}
{'Stars': 1}
{}
{'Arbeitgeber': 1}
{}
{}
{}

Comment: @geraldine can you give a printout of what your lists are in your answer, so that we can better help (what do wofo and role look like vs. what wofo2 and role2 look like)?

Comment: Sure! Thank you for your help on this!

wofo: Lichtfiguren
nachhängt
diese
Sterne
fallen
Stars
stürzen 
(but they are all in a new line)
wofo2: ['Lichtfiguren']
['nachhängt']
['diese']
['Sterne']
['fallen']
['Stars']
['stürzen']
(still all in a new line)
role: Metapher
Anker
Anker
Metapher
Metapher
Anker
(also all in a new line)
role2: ['Metapher']
['Anker']
['Anker']
['Metapher']
['Metapher']
['Anker']

Comment: @geraldine: If you want to split on any whitespace, use plain `.split()`, not `.split('\n')` (which only splits on newlines) or `.split(' ')` (which splits on all spaces, but not newlines, and will leave empty strings if there are multiple spaces in a row).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh, okay! I used \n because the words were all written in new lines and did not have spaces after them

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is completely broken is that you made keys from `wofo2` (a `list` of strings, from what I assume is a newline separated string of words in `wofo`), but your loop loops over `wofo` itself. It's legal to loop over a string, but it's going to iterate character by character, not by newline separated words, so unless the words are length one, the `dict` keys will never overlap. You want to loop over `wofo2` here, which will also let you guarantee the keys exist (using `.get()` was silencing errors here, if you'd used square bracket lookup, you'd have realized the keys you were looking for didn't exist, and were one character long).

So assuming the logic is correct, the fix for your original code is to just change:

```
for element in wofo:
```

to:

```
for element in wofo2:
```

And as a minor bonus, you can change every use of `dicitionary.get(element)` to `dicitionary[element]` (because now every key you're checking is guaranteed to be in there, and `.get`'s feature of returning `None` when it's missing is unnecessary).

And additional possible problem is that it seems you want to track when the same word from `wofo2` is seen multiple times, and track all the corresponding values from `role2`. The `dict(zip(...))` code used just keeps the last mapping seen, not all of them. If you want to keep all of them, you'd need something like:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict  # Better versions of dict for what you're doing

lemma_met = Counter()  # Avoids need to test before each increment
lemma_ank = Counter()

wofo2 = wofo.split("\n")
role2 = role.split("\n")

dicitionary = defaultdict(list)  # Use defaultdict(list) if you want to keep all duplicate mappings of the same pair of values, but if you don't care, set has cheaper lookup
                                 # defaultdict(Counter) would be good if you needed to know about duplicate mappings, but not the precise order the duplicates arrived in
for w, r in zip(wofo2, role2):
    dicitionary[w].add(r)  # Change to .append(r) if using defaultdict(list), or to dicitionary[w][r] += 1 if using defaultdict(Counter)

for element in wofo2:
    if "Metapher" in dicitionary[element]:
        lemma_met[element] += 1  # No need for conditional check; Counter treats missing key as initially zero
    elif "Anker" in dicitionary[element]:
        lemma_ank[element] += 1
```

It's also wholly possible that last loop should really not be using `wofo2` at all, especially if you just want to count how many times a word from `wofo2` mapped to `Metapher` or `Anker`; if that's the case, `defaultdict(Counter)` is the best solution, and the final loop gets *really* simple:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict  # Better versions of dict for what you're doing

lemma_met = {}
lemma_ank = {}

wofo2 = wofo.split("\n")
role2 = role.split("\n")

dicitionary = defaultdict(Counter)
for w, r in zip(wofo2, role2):
    dicitionary[w][r] += 1

for element, rolecnts in dicitionary.items():
    if "Metapher" in rolecnts:
        lemma_met[element] = rolecnts["Metapher"]
    if "Anker" in rolecnts:
        lemma_ank[element] = rolecnts["Anker"]
```

or something to that effect (where you count all roles occurrences for each unique `wofo2` up front, and the final loop is really just copying over the counts for the roles you actually care about).

Comment: sorry for taking a minute to answer, I had to try out all the solutions. you were certainly right about .get() hiding an error - as soon as I changed it to [], I got an error message. The last solution with defaultdict counter you posted helped a lot, but the anwer is still a bit weird? It is similar to what the solution by Andrew Ryan got. The first few entries of lemma_met are: {'Lichtfiguren': 1}
{}
{}
{'Sterne': 1}
{'fallen': 1}
Maybe there really is a problem with the original lists?
Thank you so much for your help by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

wofo = "Lichtfiguren\nnachhängt\ndiese\nSterne\nfallen".split("\n")
role =  "Metapher\nAnker\nAnker\nMetapher\nMetapher".split("\n")

dictionary = list(zip(wofo, role))
lemma_met = dict(Counter(z[0] for z in dictionary if z[1] == 'Metapher'))
lemma_ank = dict(Counter(z[0] for z in dictionary if z[1] == 'Anker'))

print(lemma_met)
print(lemma_ank)
```

Output:

```
{'Lichtfiguren': 1, 'Sterne': 1, 'fallen': 1}
{'nachhängt': 1, 'diese': 1}
```

Or you can skip the `zip` step:

```
wofo = "Lichtfiguren\nnachhängt\ndiese\nSterne\nfallen".split('\n')
role =  "Metapher\nAnker\nAnker\nMetapher\nMetapher".split('\n')

lemma_met = dict(Counter(word for i,word in enumerate(wofo) if role[i] == 'Metapher'))
lemma_ank = dict(Counter(word for i,word in enumerate(wofo) if role[i] == 'Anker'))
```

Note, all these methods require looping over the lists multiple times. A single `for` loop like in the original code is a bit more efficient. The advantage of these methods over a loop is that it will be easier to add more words to "role", like adverb. adjective, etc. Example:

```
results = {}
for r in set(role):
    results[r] = dict(Counter(word for i,word in enumerate(wofo) if role[i] == r))
```

Using a `for` loop.

```
lemma_met = {}
lemma_ank = {}
for i,word in enumerate(wofo):
    if role[i] == "Metapher":
        lemma_met[word] = lemma_met.get(word, 0) + 1
    else:
        lemma_ank[word] = lemma_ank.get(word, 0) + 1
```

*Note: all these examples assume the lists are the same size!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the for loop (because I am most familiar with this one). For some reason it gives me an index error? (IndexError: string index out of range) However, the lists are all the same size. 
The first one gave me a type error (TypeError: 'list' object is not callable). And the second one gave me this solution: {'Lichtfiguren': 1}
{}
{}
{'Sterne': 1}
{'fallen': 1}
I think there might be something wrong with the lists?

Comment: Maybe the issue is I used the variables `wofo` and `role` to be the already split list of words but it looks like you use `wofo2` and `role2`.

Comment: They were split everywhere except for the for loop. Now the answer there is the same as the other solutions: {'Lichtfiguren': 1}
{}
{}
{'Sterne': 1}
{'fallen': 1}
{}
  I don't know why this happens with every solution that was suggested here? Maybe my entire code is just broken...

Comment: Maybe the data has something in it you aren't expecting. I can't imagine how those empty dictionaries are getting in there. Or why you have multiple dictionaries. All the code in my post will produce single dictionaries. Ex: `{'Lichtfiguren': 1, 'Sterne': 1, 'fallen': 1}` instead of `{'Lichtfiguren': 1} {} {} {'Sterne': 1} {'fallen': 1} {}` Here's a link to show it in action: https://replit.com/@JohnnyMopp/LastUpsetTechnician

Comment: Yes, maybe. Especially because multiple solutions now have produced the same weird result with the empty dictionaries. I will try to check the text document and the wofo and role lists again!